# Store and Retrieve values from web.config

Tags: vb.net, web-config, asp.net-3.5

I built a small website and there will be only one admin, so in the admin panel I am asking for a password with a value that I do not retrieve from a database, I just hard coded it in the function in code behind, I know this is wrong though I don't know why.

So is hard coding it in web.config the right thing to do? and how?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

As far as it being wrong... the problem is that if you ever need to change it, and it's hardcoded in your codebehind, you need to recompile,republish, re-deploy your website, whereas a change to the web.config can be done without doing this.

You could put it in an AppSetting in the web.config like so.

```
<appSettings>
   <add key="AdminPassword" value="ASDF1234" />
</appSettings>
```

and use this code to retrieve it

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AdminPassword"].ToString()
```

Though I'd have a look at this.

https://web.archive.org/web/20211029043331/https://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/021506-1.aspx

It covers encrypting sections of your web.config

Comment: Do you have to restart the web server (IIS) in order for the **web.config** to take effect? Is there a better way?

Comment: seems like the solution, but why would I get the ol' "Cannot resolve symbol ToString?"

Comment: I know this is really old but... but the syntax should be: `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("AdminPassword").ToString()`

Comment: You put a c# syntax AppSettings["AdminPassword"]
Should be AppSettings("AdminPassword")

Comment: I think this syntax for VS 2015 is actually `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.GetValues("AdminPassword").ToString()`

Answer (score 3):

Nothing wrong with Eoin's suggestion for tiny projects but if your project may someday need more than 1 admin and different types of users roles. I would take the hit and setup ASP membership.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998347.aspx

You can use integrate it into windows or use a database and it's not too hard to setup. Especially if you use the built in config tool in IIS.

Comment: yep. absolutely agreed. it's envariably worth taking the hit as well cos you just know you'll have to do it sooner or later.